# Comparing string word to line in .txt file - language limitations?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, setlocale, regional-settings

I'm currently working on some simple spell-checker / dictionary for my exam project.
Nothing special, but I've encountered problem while comparing words that use regional characters - in this case polish ones.

How does it work?
 1. User enters specific word.
 2. Program checks, if user's word exist in dictionary (a.txt).
 3. Program shows results.

For test purposes I've limited dictionary only to 'a'-words, since whole dictionary in polish weights about 38MB, so I'll have to implement some kind of alghoritm to speed up search process, but that's not the case right now.

Basically program works fine. When user enters word such as: auto, abakus, atom - everything is fine.
But error occurs, when user enter words that include regional symbols, such as 'abażur', 'aranżując' etc.

setLocale doesn't really help.
I've tried to attribute each regional character to a specific ascii number - it actually works for cout's and cin's, but not for comparing strings.
Any more suggestions? I'm running out of ideas.

```
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

string line;
string word;
cout << tr("Zazółć gęślą jaźń") << endl;    //test line1
cout << "Abażur" << endl;                   //test line2
cout << "Enter word: ";
cin >> word;
ifstream myfile("a.txt");                   //open dictionary
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        //cout << line << '\n';
        if (word == line)                   //compare current words
        {
            cout << "Word exist in dictionary!" << endl << word << endl << line << endl;
            flag1 = 1;
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    if (flag1 == 1)
    {
        cout << "Search successful!" << endl;
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Search failed! No such word in dictionary." << endl;
        myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
cin >> a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It works fine on my system. What error are you getting?

Comment: One suggestion: use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @16tons how's that possible? Do you have polish dictionary file? :D
I've uploaded it here: just put it in the current code folder ;)
https://www.sendspace.com/file/s0q9fq

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Just tried that. Changed to wstrings, wifstream, wcout, and wcin - but problem still persist. Feel free to download sample dictonary file ;)

Comment: I am running one of the ubuntu linux flavors. Created a text file called a.txt with 5 words, including the ones you said gives you error. Compiled your program and ran it, runs just fine!

That makes me think the problem in your program is elsewhere, not the polish characters... Hence I asked what error you are getting?

Comment: @16tons Program just returns with failure message, that is "Search failed!", but ends properly.
Visual Studio 2015 Community with update 3 here. Could this be a problem?

Comment: I don't know if that could be the problem. I suggest the following: 

Create a simple program, load 2 strings with the same Polish characters like (std::string one = "Abażur") and use comparison operator on them

That way you'll be able to see what happens if you do (one == two) kinda comparison. If that fails, then you can try to compare them using something like (strcmp (one.c_str(), two.c_str()).

Comment: @16tons Ok, actually friend of mine found solution for that.
First of all, i had to change setlocale into setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL"), then open dictionary file (a.txt) in VS and save it in central european (dos) - codepage 852.
Problem solved :D Thanks anyway ^^